# ActionScript - How to remove an item/object from screen through if statement condition

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make a drag and drop game, basically I have three conditions, if the dragged item is placed on a target which is not what it should match then take the user to another frame (game over), however if the item that is placed matches with the target then just place the item on top of the target.

This is my code :

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

var objectoriginalX:Number;
var objectoriginalY:Number;

plastic_1.buttonMode = true;
plastic_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
plastic_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, plasticwastetarget);            

function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.startDrag();
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    objectoriginalX = event.target.x;
    objectoriginalY = event.target.y;
}

function plasticwastetarget(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.stopDrag();

    var matchingTargetName:String = "plasticWaste";
    var matchingTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(matchingTargetName);
    if(event.target.dropTarget.parent !== matchingTarget)
    {       
        gotoAndStop(20);
    } 
    else if(event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent ==  matchingTarget)
    {
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, plasticwastetarget);
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = matchingTarget.x;
        event.target.y = matchingTarget.y;      
    }
    else
    {   
        event.target.buttonMode = true;
        gotoAndStop(20);
        // How can I remove the item from screen and just go to frame 20
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is, if the user place an item on a target which is not supposed to match then the item just stays on screen throughout the animation, is there anyway I can remove or hide that object/item ??

this is the check I am making :

```
else
{   
    event.target.buttonMode = true;
    gotoAndStop(20);
    // How can I remove the item from screen and just go to frame 20
}
```

I am new using ActionScript and I couldn't manage to fix this problem please can someone help me fix this issue, Thanks.

Comment: You can hide it using : `item.visible = false;`, and to remove it : `item.parent.removeChild(item);` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
else
{   
    event.target.buttonMode = true;
    gotoAndStop(20);
    // How can I remove the item from screen and just go to frame 20
    event.target.parent.removeChild(event.target); 
}
```